# Designing mobile website from existing desktop website

Tags: c#, asp.net, mobile, mobile-website

I was asked to create a mobile version separately (I know it's bad but the project was too big to start over) for an existing website designed in asp.net.  I copied the code behind files to create the new aspx files in a separate "Mobile" folder but now I am getting an error that says the Type "already contains a definition for[...]".  I know this has to do with the duplicate use of certain things but how do I go about fixing it now?

Answer (score 0):

If you just copied the code-behind files and didn't change the namespace or page class names, you'll get conflicts. It would probably be easiest to rename your namespaces in the mobile folder to include the word "mobile". Make sure you remember to change the code-behind reference in your aspx as well.